# How can I create an installation package for a Mac OS application without having a Mac?

Tags: macos, installation

I have a C# application that works great in Linux and Windows. Now I want to make an installation package for the Mac OS but I don't have anything running it in order to develop it / test it. The software is open source, so I don't want to put money into buying yet another laptop just to test it.

Is there a way to create some kind of installer / package for this C# application without actually needing to have a Mac? I even made a `.deb` package for Linux. Isn't it possible to somehow convert it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how fancy you want to get with the installer.  I'd start with something simple like building a package for [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/).

That's all command-line, though.  If you think your Mac users would be unhappy installing an running from the command-line, you'll have to look into more sophisticated solutions.  Mac GUI applications are traditionally built into `.app` bundles.  Unfortunately for you, C# does not have lots of support for cross-compiling to the Mac.  It's *possible*, but it's going to take a lot of trial and error, which will be way more frustrating without a test machine to see if you're doing it right.

You might try CPack (part of [CMake](http://www.cmake.org)).  CMake doesn't really do C# (otherwise it'd be perfect for you), but you may be able to point CPack at the completed binaries and get it to bundle them up for the Mac for you.  You could also use CMake/CPack to build a dummy Mac application and then you'd be able to swap out all the pieces for your own binaries.